# AWS Elasticsearch query is very slow

Tags: elasticsearch

Below query is taking time. can anyone let me know, what is wrong with the query

```json
GET patentmaster/_search
{
  "_source": [
    "patentPguid"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "factValues.factPGUID": {
                        "query": "urn:fact:patent:000000000000000000000000000001",
                        "operator": "OR",
                        "prefix_length": 0,
                        "max_expansions": 50,
                        "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                        "lenient": false,
                        "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "factValues.factValue": {
                        "query": "CN",
                        "operator": "OR",
                        "prefix_length": 0,
                        "max_expansions": 50,
                        "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                        "lenient": false,
                        "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "factValues.sourcePGUID": {
                        "query": "urn:source:000000000000000000000000000020",
                        "operator": "OR",
                        "prefix_length": 0,
                        "max_expansions": 50,
                        "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                        "lenient": false,
                        "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                "boost": 1
              }
            },
            "path": "factValues",
            "ignore_unmapped": false,
            "score_mode": "sum",
            "boost": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "factValues.factPGUID": {
                        "query": "urn:fact:patent:000000000000000000000000000002",
                        "operator": "OR",
                        "prefix_length": 0,
                        "max_expansions": 50,
                        "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                        "lenient": false,
                        "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "wildcard": {
                      "factValues.factValue": {
                        "wildcard": "U*",
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "factValues.sourcePGUID": {
                        "query": "urn:source:000000000000000000000000000020",
                        "operator": "OR",
                        "prefix_length": 0,
                        "max_expansions": 50,
                        "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                        "lenient": false,
                        "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                "boost": 1
              }
            },
            "path": "factValues",
            "ignore_unmapped": false,
            "score_mode": "sum",
            "boost": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "factValues.factPGUID": {
                        "query": "urn:fact:patent:000000000000000000000000000282",
                        "operator": "OR",
                        "prefix_length": 0,
                        "max_expansions": 50,
                        "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                        "lenient": false,
                        "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "factValues.factValue": {
                        "query": "202010006967.6",
                        "operator": "OR",
                        "prefix_length": 0,
                        "max_expansions": 50,
                        "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                        "lenient": false,
                        "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "factValues.sourcePGUID": {
                        "query": "urn:source:000000000000000000000000000020",
                        "operator": "OR",
                        "prefix_length": 0,
                        "max_expansions": 50,
                        "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                        "lenient": false,
                        "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                "boost": 1
              }
            },
            "path": "factValues",
            "ignore_unmapped": false,
            "score_mode": "sum",
            "boost": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "factValues.factPGUID": {
                        "query": "urn:fact:patent:000000000000000000000000000283",
                        "operator": "OR",
                        "prefix_length": 0,
                        "max_expansions": 50,
                        "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                        "lenient": false,
                        "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "factValues.factValue": {
                        "query": "original",
                        "operator": "OR",
                        "prefix_length": 0,
                        "max_expansions": 50,
                        "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                        "lenient": false,
                        "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "factValues.sourcePGUID": {
                        "query": "urn:source:000000000000000000000000000020",
                        "operator": "OR",
                        "prefix_length": 0,
                        "max_expansions": 50,
                        "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                        "lenient": false,
                        "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                "boost": 1
              }
            },
            "path": "factValues",
            "ignore_unmapped": false,
            "score_mode": "sum",
            "boost": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "factValues.factPGUID": {
                        "query": "urn:fact:patent:000000000000000000000000000276",
                        "operator": "OR",
                        "prefix_length": 0,
                        "max_expansions": 50,
                        "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                        "lenient": false,
                        "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "factValues.factValue": {
                        "query": "CN",
                        "operator": "OR",
                        "prefix_length": 0,
                        "max_expansions": 50,
                        "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                        "lenient": false,
                        "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "factValues.sourcePGUID": {
                        "query": "urn:source:000000000000000000000000000020",
                        "operator": "OR",
                        "prefix_length": 0,
                        "max_expansions": 50,
                        "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                        "lenient": false,
                        "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                "boost": 1
              }
            },
            "path": "factValues",
            "ignore_unmapped": false,
            "score_mode": "sum",
            "boost": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "factValues.factPGUID": {
                              "query": "urn:fact:patent:000000000000000000000000000266",
                              "operator": "OR",
                              "prefix_length": 0,
                              "max_expansions": 50,
                              "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                              "lenient": false,
                              "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                              "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                              "boost": 1
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "factValues.factValue": {
                              "query": "A39",
                              "operator": "OR",
                              "prefix_length": 0,
                              "max_expansions": 50,
                              "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                              "lenient": false,
                              "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                              "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                              "boost": 1
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "factValues.sourcePGUID": {
                              "query": "urn:source:000000000000000000000000000020",
                              "operator": "OR",
                              "prefix_length": 0,
                              "max_expansions": 50,
                              "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                              "lenient": false,
                              "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                              "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                              "boost": 1
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ],
                      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                      "boost": 1
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "factValues.factPGUID": {
                              "query": "urn:fact:patent:000000000000000000000000000266",
                              "operator": "OR",
                              "prefix_length": 0,
                              "max_expansions": 50,
                              "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                              "lenient": false,
                              "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                              "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                              "boost": 1
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "factValues.factValue": {
                              "query": "U39",
                              "operator": "OR",
                              "prefix_length": 0,
                              "max_expansions": 50,
                              "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                              "lenient": false,
                              "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                              "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                              "boost": 1
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "factValues.sourcePGUID": {
                              "query": "urn:source:000000000000000000000000000020",
                              "operator": "OR",
                              "prefix_length": 0,
                              "max_expansions": 50,
                              "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                              "lenient": false,
                              "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                              "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                              "boost": 1
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ],
                      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                      "boost": 1
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                "boost": 1
              }
            },
            "path": "factValues",
            "ignore_unmapped": false,
            "score_mode": "sum",
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "patentPguid": {
              "query": "urn:patent:bbc9fb96-e3fe-0cbf-ca57-93746f03a297",
              "operator": "OR",
              "prefix_length": 0,
              "max_expansions": 50,
              "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
              "lenient": false,
              "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
              "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Java Query:

```
    QueryBuilder countryCodeQuery = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("factValues",
            QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("factValues.factPGUID", FactValuesEnums.COUNTRY_CODE.getPguid()))
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("factValues.factValue", countryCodeOfCurrentPatent))
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("factValues.sourcePGUID", FactValuesEnums.FLD_MAT.getPguid())),
            ScoreMode.Total);

    QueryBuilder kindCodeQuery = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("factValues",
            QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("factValues.factPGUID", FactValuesEnums.KIND_CODE.getPguid()))
                    .must(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("factValues.factValue",
                            kindCodeOfCurrentPatent.startsWith("A") ? "U*" : "A*"))
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("factValues.sourcePGUID", FactValuesEnums.FLD_MAT.getPguid())),
            ScoreMode.Total);

    QueryBuilder applicationIdNumberTextQuery = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("factValues",
            QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("factValues.factPGUID",
                            FactValuesEnums.PRIORITIES_PRIORITY_APPLICATION_NUMBER_CONTENT.getPguid()))
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("factValues.factValue", applicationIdNumberTextOfCurrentPatent))
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("factValues.sourcePGUID", FactValuesEnums.FLD_MAT.getPguid())),
            ScoreMode.Total);

    QueryBuilder applicationIdNumberFormQuery = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("factValues",
            QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("factValues.factPGUID",
                            FactValuesEnums.PRIORITIES_PRIORITY_APPLICATION_NUMBER_FORM.getPguid()))
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("factValues.factValue", Constants.ORIGINAL))
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("factValues.sourcePGUID", FactValuesEnums.FLD_MAT.getPguid())),
            ScoreMode.Total);

    QueryBuilder applicationIdCountryCodeQuery = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("factValues",
            QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("factValues.factPGUID",
                            FactValuesEnums.PRIORITIES_PRIORITY_APPLICATION_APPLICATION_COUNTRY_CODE.getPguid()))
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("factValues.factValue", applicationIdCountryCode))
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("factValues.sourcePGUID", FactValuesEnums.FLD_MAT.getPguid())),
            ScoreMode.Total);

    QueryBuilder prioritiesPriorityCodeQuery = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("factValues", QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("factValues.factPGUID",
                            FactValuesEnums.PRIORITIES_PRIORITY_CODE.getPguid()))
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("factValues.factValue", "A39"))
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("factValues.sourcePGUID", FactValuesEnums.FLD_MAT.getPguid())))
            .should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("factValues.factPGUID",
                            FactValuesEnums.PRIORITIES_PRIORITY_CODE.getPguid()))
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("factValues.factValue", "U39"))
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("factValues.sourcePGUID", FactValuesEnums.FLD_MAT.getPguid()))),
            ScoreMode.Total);

    QueryBuilder mainQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(countryCodeQuery).must(kindCodeQuery)
            .must(applicationIdNumberTextQuery).must(applicationIdNumberFormQuery)
            .must(applicationIdCountryCodeQuery).must(prioritiesPriorityCodeQuery)
            .mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("patentPguid", recordPGUID))
            ;

//      SourceFilter sourceFilter = new FetchSourceFilter(new String[] { "patent.PGUID" }, null);
        NativeSearchQuery nativeSearchQueryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(mainQuery)
//              .withSourceFilter(sourceFilter)
                .build();
        // System.out.println(boolQuery);
        long count = 
 
 
 
 elasticsearchOperations.count(nativeSearchQueryBuilder,IndexCoordinates.of(ElasticSearchConstants.PATENT_INDEX));
```

[image]

[image]

And below is our json structure of record in ES, this is one object we have multiple there.

[image]

Comment: From what I see, you're making a very heavy usage of nested queries and that might be one of the reasons of what's causing the slowness you see. But again, it depends... on your data volume, one your hardware, on the read/write load of your cluster... If you can provide more insights, it'll be easier to zero in on the issue, otherwise we're just shooting in the dark.

Comment: Images are added @Val

Comment: Thanks! I see you have 151 `factValues` **nested** documents. Ouch, that hurts! As it seems your query is ONLY searching on that array, maybe your data design is not the best suited for the task. You might have MUCH better results by storing `factValues` in an independent index as standalone documents

Comment: Actually at this time, I cannot change data design, can I do anything with query to achieve good results.

Comment: Hard to tell honestly. Heavily banking on nested documents goes against all best practice recommendations regarding efficient data design for ES.

Comment: you could scale up your cluster size, but that's about it unless you restructure